# Javascript nested if statement when 1 is not in the array

Tags: javascript

Hi I am learning if statement at the moment..bear with me

```js
let x = [3,4,5,6,7]
if(3 in x){
  if(1 in x){
    console.log(1 in x)
  }
}


console.log(8 in x)
console.log(1000 in x)
```

Just wonder why   `console.log(1 in x)` can be true? Since there is no 1 in x.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a `1` in x.  It is 4, the element at index `1`.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand this behavior we need to look into the [in operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in).

Let's quote MDN:

> The in operator returns true if the specified property is in the specified object or its prototype chain.

In JavaScript, arrays are objects under the hood. When you type `if (1 in x)`, you are really checking if the `x` object has a property called `1`.

Let's inspect your code a bit closer:

```
let x = [3,4,5,6,7]
```

Since the array has 5 elements, the `x` object has 5 properties:

```
0 in x // true
1 in x // true
2 in x // true
3 in x // true
4 in x // true

5 in x // false!
```

Summing in up: when you use the **in operator**, you are checking the keys of the object and not the values.

Comment: Clear and concise, appreciated!!

Answer (score 2):

Your array has 5 elements indexed from 0 to 4. You'll get true for each statement `0 - 4 in x` because it's checking whether your array has an element at the given index. If you want to check if an array contains an element I recommend you to use [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

```
if (x.includes(1))
{
    // Should never enter here since your array has no element of value 1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The basic is explained in the MDN (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in)
but the basic is that `in` operator checks for a property of an  object and because in javascript array is an object and because the array that you crated could be represented like:

```
let y = { 
    '0': 3,
    '1': 4,
    '2': 5,
    '3': 6,
    '4': 7
}
```

So you could access the array element by index is the same in javascript as accessing property of an object. So yours x[0] is similar to mine y[0] and both returns 3. So in your example you will have `2 in x === true` and `0 in x === true` etc.